# apt update && apt upgrade -> package can be upgraded

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates

Using Ubuntu server 18.04. When I try with "apt update && apt upgrade", I get a warning:

```
1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it.
```

If I then try with suggestion, I get:

```
Listing... Done
libneon27/bionic-updates 0.30.2-3~ubuntu18.04.1 i386 [upgradable from: 0.30.2-2build1]
N: There is 1 additional version. Please use the '-a' switch to see it
```

What is wrong (if something)?

UPDATE:
"apt-cache policy libneon27":

```
libneon27:
  Installed: 0.30.2-2build1
  Candidate: 0.30.2-3~ubuntu18.04.1
  Version table:
     0.30.2-3~ubuntu18.04.1 500
        500 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 Packages
 *** 0.30.2-2build1 500
        500 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy libneon27` to the question.

Comment: Do you mean that the package is not upgraded even after `apt upgrade`? What about `apt full-upgrade`?

Comment: @fkraiem - isn't "apt full-upgrade" similar as "dist-upgrade"? I don't want to try it :-) But it is interesting, almost all packages are upgraded, but then I get a message that "1 package can be upgraded".

Comment: Well, have fun then...

Comment: I want to stay on 18.04 ...

Comment: What is the answer to this?